# Whonix hidden service

Tags: onion-services, whonix

I'm playing around with whonix and hidden services. I've followed this tutorial (except Step 3: Configure Onion Services Authentication) 
https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Onion_Services#Hidden_Webserver but can't seem to make it work. 
I've used the Virtualbox images Whonix-CLI-14.0.1.4.4. All the steps shown in the section Debugging work,

> UWT_DEV_PASSTHROUGH=1 curl 10.152.152.11:80

on the Workstation shows that the webserver is up and running.
However i can't reach the test page from another tor browser. (even after waiting >30 minutes)

How can i pin down the issue?

Comment: Whonix version `14.0.1.4.4` is outdated, deprecated, [unsupported](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Unsupported).